# splitting functions in parts is good for memory management?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I been trying to learn about garbage collector to make more memory friendly java apps.
I have a question about garbage collector, lets assume that we have a function like that:

```
public void personWork(){
List<Person> firstPersonList = personService.getFirstPersonList();
List<Person> secondPersonList = personService.getSecondPersonList();

// Do something with firstPersonList
..
..
..
// Do something with secondPersonList
..
..
..

 finish the function
}
```

I can also make the same thing with this code

```
public void personWork(){
List<Person> firstPersonList = personService.getFirstPersonList();
List<Person> secondPersonList = personService.getSecondPersonList();

firstPersonListJob(firstPersonList);

secondPersonListJob(secondPersonList);

//finish the function
}

public void firstPersonListJob(List<Person> firstPersonList){
 // do someting with firstPersonList
}

public void secondPersonListJob(List<Person> secondPersonList){
 // do something with secondPersonList
}
```

finally i can make this too:

```
public void personWork(){


firstPersonListJob();

secondPersonListJob();

//finish the function
}

public void firstPersonListJob(){
List<Person> firstPersonList = personService.getFirstPersonList();
// do someting with firstPersonList
}

public void secondPersonListJob(){
List<Person> secondPersonList = personService.getSecondPersonList();
 // do something with secondPersonList
}
```

As I understand from the garbage collector, In order to garbage collector clean the heap, the reference of the values in heap memory must be deleted from the stack. Considuring that the first and second approach is not good for memory management because 2 List are living until the finish, but in the last approach when function 1 is finish also the firstPersonList will be deleted.

Actually I'm not sure which approach is better for memory management or do I care about that kind of thing?

Comment: I see no reason to care about trying to please the GC for methods like these. The GC doesn't collect your stale references as soon as they go out of scope anyway. Running the GC is an expensive task in and of itself and as such it makes sense that it will only run at optimal times.

Comment: In your first examples, you are materializing `secondPersonList` long before needed, i.e. you’re not needing it while processing `firstPersonList`. So the last snippet avoids having both lists in memory at the same time, which you could achieve with your earlier variants too, by reordering the code. But you may notice, how the last approach leads to the better design automatically. So use smaller functions, regardless of garbage collection. Read also [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the impact of your original method vs the methods split to multiple parts, you need to consider multiple things:

- what hardware constraints are you working with? What's your CPU load on the hardware where the app is running? How much free memory do you have?
- what are your current heap and GC settings?
- how long do these methods run for? The longer they run the longer you'll be holding on to references before the instances are dereferenced and are eligible for collection - a few ms is probably insignificant (but could depend on what your app does and what the expectations are, e.g. from an end user or Service Level Agreement point of view), if you are looking at a long running loop or thread where it's going to run for hours or days, then maybe there's a concern to be looked at
- what's does the heap usage look like for the original code vs suggested alternative?
- same question for garbage collection (have you run the app with gc logs enabled to look at the behavior?)

In general, think about avoiding patterns that would significantly impact GC behavior, e.g. tight loops instantiating millions of instances within short time periods. Otherwise, you need to profile your code and/or look at the garbage collection logs to determine if you actually have a problem to be concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand from the garbage collector, In order to garbage collector clean the heap, the reference of the values in heap memory must be deleted from the stack.

That is not strictly correct.

The actual criterion is whether the objects in the heap are reachable.  In this case, whether they are reachable via the stack variables.

The actual definition for reachable (JLS 12.6.1) is as follows:

> "A *reachable* object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread."

Now, clearly deleting the references for those lists from the stack (and registers) for a thread would be sufficient to make them unreachable.  But a list could also be unreachable if the JVM can determine that the variable won't be used again by the current thread.

So, in the first version of your code, the JVM *could* determine that `firstPersonList` is never used after the `firstPersonListJob(...)` call, and therefore it has become unreachable by the time that the `secondPersonListJob()` call has been made!

> Considering that the first and second approach is not good for memory management because 2 List are living until the finish, but in the last approach when function 1 is finish also the `firstPersonList` will be deleted.

As I explained, the premise for this reasoning is not *necessarily* true.  It depends on how sophisticated the GC + JIT + whatever are.

But assuming it is true.  What then?

Solutions include.

1. Your final version (or a minor variation) is one solution.
2. A second solution would be to assign `null` to `firstPersonList` after the `firstPersonListJob(...)` call.
3. The final solution is to just leave this alone.  (Q: What?  A: Read on!)

Unless these lists are really large, it is unlikely to make any difference whether `firstPersonList` is garbage collected immediately ... or a bit later.  These objects will most likely be in Eden space, and cost of collecting now versus next time will be small.

The only scenarios where it could matter are if the lists are large enough that they are occupying a substantial proportion of the total heap space.  But if you are in that situation, there are other things you could do:

- increase the max heap space (assuming you have enough RAM)
- modify the application logic so that the lists don't need to be so large (e.g. better DB queries), or
- look for memory leaks, etcetera that are causing the Old generation to fill up.

As a general rule Java is memory hungry.  Garbage collectors all work best if they have plenty of free space to work with.  The cost of a GC is mostly in dealing with the objects that are not garbage.  So, naturally, if the proportion of garbage to non-garbage is smaller, the GC is expending more effort for the same amount of reclaimed space.  If you try to *squeeze* the Java heap limits to "save space", it costs CPU time, you get more major collections, and you run a greater risk of missing "pause time" goals.